# Create dataframe from dictionary with column names

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to create a dataframe with dictionary keys and values in two different columns then name then name the columns with string names

Here is my dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'amd_0': 102, 'amd_3': 11}
```

Column names:

```
columns = ['column1', column2']
```

Desired output:

```
column1 column2
amd_0   102
amd_3   11
```

I tried `from_dict` but I'm having a hard time naming the columns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dataframe using the dictionary items and specify the `columns` list as the columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=columns)
df
```

|  | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | amd_0 | 102 |
| 1 | amd_3 | 11 |

Answer (score 2):

Why would `to_dict` be your choice?  You already HAVE a dict.  You need to convert that TO a dataframe.

```
my_dict = {'amd_0': 102, 'amd_3': 11}
columns = ['column1', 'column2']

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( my_dict.items(), columns=columns )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  column1  column2
0   amd_0      102
1   amd_3       11
```

Comment: to specify, `to_dict()` takes a dataframe and returns a dictionary, not the other way around

Comment: my bad, I made the edit when I realized my typo

Answer (score 0):

I realized I over-complicated things, but will leave my answer up as it will work in some edge cases. One of which being even if your `columns` list were longer than the number of `my_dict` items.

```
data = {col:[k, v] for col, k, v in zip(columns, *my_dict.items())}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output:

  column1  column2
0   amd_0      102
1   amd_3       11
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not the best method but this is the first thing that came to mind:

```
my_dict = {'amd_0': 102, 'amd_3': 11}
cols = ['column1', 'column2']
df=pd.DataFrame(my_dict,index=[0]).T.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={'index':cols[0],0:cols[1]})
```

Answer (score -1):

you want to use this format if you want to specify the column names

```
my_dict = {"column1": ['amd_0', 'amd_3'], 'column2': [102, 11]}
print(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))
```

or this format if you want to specify rows too

```
my_dict = {"column1": {'row 1': 'amd_0', 'row 2': 'amd_3'},
       'column2': {'row 1': 102, 'row 2': 11}}
print(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))
```